# Pointer To Pointer passed by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Just to check: if i want to pass by ref a double pointer `float **ptr` through a function, should i declare it as:

```
void Func(float **&ptr)
```

or

```
Func(float **&&ptr)
```

?

Comment: `&&` is an [rvalue reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

Comment: && has a different meaning

Comment: Use `Func(float **&ptr)`. Such questions can be answered by a [good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), or even by trial and error.

Comment: Don't let the "pointer" part confuse you. To pass **any type** `T` by reference, write the function to take `T&`. For a `float**` that means `float**&`.

Comment: Are you sure you want a reference to a pointer to a pointer? While it might be the right thing to do, be sure. That much indirection is often a sign of overthinking the problem or not thinking far enough ahead.

Comment: @user4581301 and it is a missed opportunity to join [the three star programmer club](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I got it !

Answer (score 3):

*Converting a comment to an answer*.

Don't let the "pointer" part confuse you. To pass any type `T` by reference, write the function to take `T&`. For a `float**` that means `float**&`.